# How to get all data from forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

We have created the app and its working fine using below link
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/account/

On this we need to get all data like buildings,floors,rooms,spaces,equipments etc.
(All assets details which is included in uploaded file)
we need to get all the elements and stored in separate datatable.

Is it possible to get / which area we want to use.
kindly please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to get the properties and store.

You can use [this Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) to get the properties.